# Throttle TPS for an external service that triggers lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, throttling

Assume there are two services A, and B, B being owned by me. There are messages being sent from the service A that service B needs to process. B doesn't need to return any response to A. Rather, it just needs to send updates to service C.

Now the service A has an SNS, which is subscribed by the service B. B has a lambda function that is invoked by messages from the SNS.

Service A and B have an agreement that A will send the notifications to B with a TPS of T. Service B needs to implement a TPS limiter that can make sure that the agreement is followed, and throttle if it isn't.

To be more precise, the number of invocations of lambda, per second is to be limited.

Notice that the concurrent execution limit of lambda might not work here, as each request might be completed in less than a second.

Also a SQS FIFO queue can also be used, with T message group IDs, and T workers, but this has the same problem as mentioned above.

Any standard way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throttling comes out of the box using API gateway. It can be used to throttle requests if a TPS is crossed. This will give the client an 429 status.